# Bug (of hidden feature) in reputation counting

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, hidden-features

Test case:

1. Hit daily cap
2. Ask question and accept correct answer (+2 reputation as it should be)
3. Get a downvote (-2 reputation)
4. Get an upvote (+2 reputation, imho it's a bug, because I've got 202 points with upvotes).

Comment: If you associate your accounts, you can get 100 rep.

Comment: Cool)) how can I do that? cannot see any link in my profile

Comment: Hit the __accounts__ tab.

Comment: Ah, you got it.

Comment: I think that rep from accepting an answer doesn't count towards the cap, whether it's the 15 point you get from having an answer accepted or the 2 points you get from accepting an answer.

Comment: @ChrisF, I don't think it counts either, but usually an upvote after the downvote, won't do anything (I thought).

Comment: @Lance - I think there's been a change recently that corrected that particular "bug" (though don't quote me on that!)

Comment: @ChrisF, ahh, I'll have to keep my eyes open for that.

Comment: I'm waiting with breathless anticipation for Jeff to close this as [status-bydesign].

Answer (score 1):

At least it's a good bug, instead of penalizing you, you get rewarded.

I think we could eliminate half the questions on meta if we could make the rep cap simple and streamlined.

Comment: Indeed, maybe it's not a bug. But at least, at first glance it looks strange.

Comment: ...and eliminate most of the other half if we made reputation recalcs regular and obvious!

Answer (score 1):

These downvote reversals will now give back the proper amount of reputation (including  respecting the reputation cap).